# X-Path Query performance

Tags: performance, xpath

Which of the following queries are considered heavier performance wise:

```
//*/*/*/*/*
```

or

```
//ancestor-or-self::*/ancestor-or-self::*/ancestor-or-self::*/ancestor-or-self::*/ancestor-or-self::*
```

or

```
/descendant-or-self::*/*/*/*
```

To my understanding the second would be more complex to compute?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) Too broad (2) No context (3) No processor stated (4) No measurements taken (5) People asking performance questions suffering from 1-4 nearly never have actual performance problems anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About time of execution: it does not have a noticeable difference due to the fact that exist a lot of affecting factors, but anyway with almost identical tiny execution time of each requests.
On the current page each of requests performed on average in 0.07–0.09µs; 1µs = 1second * 10^-6.

```js
let arrExecutionTime = [];
function getAverageExecutionTime(locator) {
    let maxIteration = 1000;
    let timeTotal = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < maxIteration; i++) {
        let executionTimeStart = performance.now();
        let arrNode = document.evaluate(locator, document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
        arrExecutionTime.push(performance.now() - executionTimeStart);
    }

    for (let k = 0; k < arrExecutionTime.length; k++) {
        timeTotal += arrExecutionTime[k];
    }

    let avgExecutionTime = timeTotal / arrExecutionTime.length;
    console.log(`avgExecutionTime: ${avgExecutionTime}µs \nafter ${maxIteration} iterations \nfor locator:\"${locator}\"`);
}

getAverageExecutionTime("//*/*/*/*/*");
getAverageExecutionTime("//ancestor-or-self::*/ancestor-or-self::*/ancestor-or-self::*/ancestor-or-self::*/ancestor-or-self::*");
getAverageExecutionTime("/descendant-or-self::*/*/*/*");
```